# Cannot animate ContentControl background color but works with Foreground

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, animation

I'm trying to animate the selection change of a Listbox in Windows Phone 8. The following animation Works:

```
<ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ContentControl.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Duration="00:00:00.25" From="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundColor}" To="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}" />
```

But the next one does not work (System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve TargetProperty (ContentControl.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color) on specified object.

```
<ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ContentControl.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Duration="00:00:00.25" From="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundColor}" To="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}" />
```

For the life of me that I cannot spot the reason.

Comment: Try to set an explicit default `Background` on your `ContentControl`...

Comment: nemesv: WTF??? You are right. But does that mean that the property does not exist if it has not a value set????

Comment: The problem is that the `Background` is `null` is default, see also in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to explicitly set the `Background` property to something on your `ContentControl` to make the animation work.

You need this because the [default value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.background%28v=vs.95%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) of the `Background` property is `null` so when the animation parses the expression `(ContentControl.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)` it cannot access the `Color` property of the `null`.

And it works with the  `Foreground` because the [default of value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.foreground%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) the `Foreground` property is a black brush so it is set to a valid non null value by default.

Comment: Then the problema is on the exception. It should be a NullReferenceException instead of something saying that cannot resolve the property! I had to invest around 2 hours with that :(

Comment: Yes the exception message is quite misleading here.